# Проблема с перегрузкой оператора

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Проблема с перегрузкой оператора - для данного класса

```
class mvector
{
public:
    mvector();
    mvector(int a);
    mvector(const mvector &a);

    void PrintByCount(int a);
    int GetLength();
    int* GetStart();

    friend mvector& operator-(mvector a,mvector b);
private:
    int length;
    int* begin;
};
```

Определение оператора

```
mvector& operator-(mvector a,mvector b)
{
    mvector ans(min(a.length, b.length));
    cout <<"Длинна"<< ans.length <<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < min(a.length, b.length); i++)
        ans.begin[i] = min(a.begin[i], b.begin[i]);
    cout << "ANS" << endl;
    ans.PrintByCount(5);
    cout << "ENDANS" << endl;
    return ans;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    mvector a(CheckedInput("Введите длину первого вектора",1,LLONG_MAX));
    mvector b(CheckedInput("Введите длину первого вектора", 1, LLONG_MAX));
    (a - b).PrintByCount(5);
    return 0;
}
```

В теле оператора вывод верный. А в main нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну кто же возвращает ссылку на локальную переменную! Это же ссылка в никуда: ведь локальной переменной после выхода из функции просто нет. Вообще.

Попробуйте

```
mvector& operator-(mvector a,mvector b)
```

заменить на

```
mvector operator-(mvector a,mvector b)
```

P.S. Да, вдогонку - а еще аргументы как раз вполне можно передавать по ссылке:

```
mvector operator-(const mvector& a, const mvector& b)
```

Comment: + конструктор копирования в `mvector`

Comment: @VladD А он вроде бы есть - см. объявление класса, там `mvector(const mvector &a);`

Comment: Хм, и правда, не заметил.

Answer (score 1):

семантика перегрузки операторов тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading

```
class mvector
{
  mvector(); // not implemented

public:
  ~mvector() { delete[] vals; }

  mvector(int a);
  mvector(const mvector &rhs)
    : vals(NULL)
  { *this = rhs; } 

  int size(void) const { return len; }

  int* begin(void) const { return vals; }
  int* end(void) const   { return vals+len; }

  mvector& operator-(const mvector& rhs);
  mvector& operator=(const mvector& rhs);

private:
  int len; //length;
  int* vals; // begin

};

mvector::mvector(int a)
  : len(a)
{
  vals = new int[len];
  for(int i = 0; i<len; ++i)
  {
    vals[i] = 0;
  }
}

mvector& mvector::operator=(const mvector& rhs)
{
  delete[] vals;
  len = rhs.len;

  vals = new int[len];
  for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
  {
    vals[i] = rhs.vals[i];
  }  
}

mvector& mvector::operator-(const mvector& rhs)
{
  int new_len = (len > rhs.len)?rhs.len:len;

  mvector res(new_len);
  int* res_it  = res.begin();
  const int* rhs_it  = rhs.begin();
  const int* this_it = begin();

  for (int i = 0; i < new_len; ++i)
  {
    *res_it = ((*this_it) < (*rhs_it))?(*this_it) : (*rhs_it);
    ++res_it; ++this_it; ++rhs_it;
  }

  *this = res;

  return *this;
}

mvector subst(const mvector& a, const mvector& b)
{
  mvector c(a);
  c = c-b ;
  return c;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void Print(const mvector& val)
{
  std::cout << "mvector.size is " << val.size() << std::endl;

  for(int* i = val.begin(); i != val.end(); ++i)
  {
    std::cout << "i=" << *i << std::endl;
  }
}

int main()
{
  mvector a(10);
  for(int* i = a.begin(); i != a.end(); ++i)
  {
    *i = 10;
  }

  mvector b(20);
  for(int* i = b.begin(); i != b.end(); ++i)
  {
    *i = 12;
  }

  Print(b-a); 

  mvector e = subst(c,a);
  Print(e);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Данный оператор

```
mvector& operator-(mvector a,mvector b)
^^^^^^^^
{
    mvector ans(min(a.length, b.length));
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    cout <<"Длинна"<< ans.length <<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < min(a.length, b.length); i++)
        ans.begin[i] = min(a.begin[i], b.begin[i]);
    cout << "ANS" << endl;
    ans.PrintByCount(5);
    cout << "ENDANS" << endl;
    return ans;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

некорректен, так как он возвращает ссылку на локальную переменную функции, время жизни которой заканчивается после выхода из функции. В результате программа имеет неопределенное поведение.

Правильно было бы определить оператор следующим образом

```
class mvector
{
public:
    mvector();
    mvector(int a);
    mvector(const mvector &a);

    void PrintByCount(int a);
    int GetLength() const;
                    ^^^^^^
    int* GetStart();
    const int* GetStart() const;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    // Убрать из класса friend mvector operator -( const mvector &a, const mvector &b);
private:
    int length;
    int* begin;
};

mvector operator -( const mvector &a, const mvector &b )
{
    mvector ans( std::min( a.GetLength(), b.GetLength() ) );

    std::cout <<"Длинна"<< ans.GetLength() <<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < ans.GetLength(); i++ )
        ans.GetStart()[i] = std::min( a.GetStart()[i], b.GetStart()[i]);

    std::cout << "ANS" << std::endl;
    ans.PrintByCount(5);
    std::cout << "ENDANS" << std::endl;

    return ans;
}
```

То есть нет необходимости делать этот оператор дружественным классу, так как есть все необходимые функции-члены класса для доступа к данным класса.

Также имейте в виду, что так как, похоже, у вас память выделяется динамически внутри объектов класса, то вам необходимо также объявить **копирующий оператор присваивания** и **деструктор**.